# How do I turn off Apple's iAds network?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I had Apple's iAds in my app.  Now I've removed them.  However I'm having trouble finding a "turn off" switch in itunesconnect.  **I don't want my app to receive ads any more**.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you had the foresight to design your app such that you can tell it to start refusing ads, it's unlikely that you can do much to turn the ads off in versions of the app that are currently out there. The best you can do is to remove any instances of ADBannerView from your app, rebuild, and issue an update.

I've never tried to turn off iAds, and the fact that this question has gone unanswered for as long as it has suggests that this is an unusual situation. You might call Apple Developer Relations at 1-800-633-2152 (in the US) to see if you can invalidate your agreement or take some other action that will cause Apple to stop serving you ads.

Answer (score 3):

iAds can only be disabled when the app is in an "editable" state, meaning when you submit a new binary.

When you submit the binary with the ADBannerView removed, you should be able to disable it when you set up the meta data for the new version.

From the [iTunes Connect Deveoper Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) page 129:
"Once your app has been submitted, iAd cannot be disabled. To remove ads from an app, you will need to submit a new binary with ad functionality removed"

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What exactly is the "meta data"?  Something in itunesconnect?

Comment: Right -- the app's meta data is the information about the app that you enter into iTunesConnect: price, description, rating, etc.